# Calculations involving bus routes

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am working with a college to develop their campus iOS app. One of the app's features is the ability to determine which of the campus bus routes are most applicable to getting to a destination (as well as a listing of when the bus arrives, etc).

If I have sets of long/lat data representing the stops of a route, what is the easiest way to determine the closest route to a long/lat destination point? I have over 10 roues to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to determine the closest point to a route, you can use the [Distance to a Ray or Segment](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0102/algorithm_0102.htm#Distance%20to%20Ray%20or%20Segment) formula using a lat-lng as the reference point.

There is another option, if you are using a Google Map, because the Terms of Service require that the service be used in the context of a Google Map; you may want to consider the Google Maps Distance Matrix Service[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). The service allows you to submit a request with an `origins` property, which must be an array of `google.maps.LatLng` starting points and a `destinations` property, which must be an array of `google.maps.LatLng` ending points. The `DistanceMatrixService`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixService) also allows you to define a `TravelMode`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TravelMode), which may be one of: `BICYCLING`, `DRIVING`, or `WALKING`. It has the advantage over simple distance calculation, because it accounts for the natural activity of traveling from one point to another using the existing network of streets.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic response -- I actually plan on using Google Maps for determining the walking route to the stops and to the destinations. The problem is Google's current routing system for the school transit is pretty crappy and I feel like I will have to custom code the routing logic. Does that sound right? Or is there some library interface out there that allows you to input points and get potential routes as output?

Comment: No problem; glad to help. And yes, there is a service you can use: check out the [DirectionsService Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to get familiar with how it works and when you are ready to start coding, you can use the [API-Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService) as a reference.